# Best way to store a list of latlngs in SQL

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an android app that collects `gps` points off a phone, and I have a server that I want to send the last 5 collected points, plus a `phone ID` to. On the server I am using an `SQLite` database to save this information. I have `Phone_ID` as a `double`, but what is the best way to store the 5 data points?

as five strings, and split around a comma for the lat a lng?
as one long string and split around the lat, lng then get the next pair?

Also how should I send it, as embedded data in the URL?
Or as a input string?

Comment: I would store the 5 records separately.

Comment: if you want to access each of 5 coords independently - use record-per-coord. if you don't - a single blob of several coords as CSV is fine

Comment: I will only be using the five cords at he same time, so never requesting just one of them

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on how flexible you want this to be for the future. Do you think someday you'll want to store 6 data points or maybe only 4?

#### Normalized Option

If so, you should take advantage of normalized database design and have two tables. One table to define users, and the other to define the position. Have a sequential key assigned on the user table and use that as the foreign key on the position table.

```
user_id     phone_number
1           123-456-7890

user_id     position_seq     longitude     latitude
1           1                1.234         2.345
1           2                3.456         4.567
```

#### Quick/Denormalized/Hack Option

If you don't care and just want to be done with this today, store it as a serialized array or dictionary as a string. That way you can deserialize right back into an object when you do the read.

```
phone_number     locations
123-456-7890     "[(1.234,2.345),(3.456,4.567)]"
```

Comment: Should I pass this as an input string, e.g. 123-456-789,[(1.234,2.345,3.456,4.567)(1.234,2.345,3.456,4.567)(1.234,2.345,3.456,4.567)(1.234,2.345,3.456,4.567)(1.234,2.345,3.456,4.567)]

Then use string split to extract the values?

Comment: I'm not a big java developer, but I would use something like Jackson to directly serialize the array into a string and then on retrieval cast it back to an array. You can definitely use comma separated values instead and do the parsing yourself, but I find the direct serializing/deserializing to be more robust. Here's an example: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-object-to-from-json-jackson/